# Oracle SQL Developer 23.1 "Save Password" Checkbox not working

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

Since getting a new work laptop and doing a fresh install of Oracle SQL Developer 23.1.1.345, my passwords are not saving anymore.

The "Save Password" checkbox is ticked, and I have entered and saved the connection configuration multiple times. Every time I restart the SQL Developer though, I get prompted for the password again.

I've found multiple threads talking about this problem.

Some people suggested that you have to use JDK 8 u151 or u221 at the minimum. I am currently working with OpenJDK 11.0.21, and as far as I could gather, this should still work fine, as long as the Java version is above JDK 8 u151/u221

I've found a different [thread](https://forums.oracle.com/ords/apexds/post/password-not-saving-correctly-for-mysql-and-sqlserver-conne-9486) stating that with version 23.1, saving passwords does not work correctly. The password gets saved, but when trying to log in the access is denied since the password gets stored incorrectly. As far as I could tell, this is not my problem

I'm on Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS, if anyone has any ideas what else could be the problem, please let me know.

Comment: If you suspect it is a bug, Stack Overflow isn't the right place to fix software bugs, and a post on the Oracle forms might be more useful for you.

Comment: "a different thread stating that with version 23.1, saving passwords does not work correctly." - where is this thread?

Comment: @thatjeffsmith my apologies, it seems I forgot the link. I've edited my original question. https://forums.oracle.com/ords/apexds/post/password-not-saving-correctly-for-mysql-and-sqlserver-conne-9486 this is the thread I mentioned.

Comment: @easleyfixed Still, this bug doesn't seem correlated to me, because here the password actually does get saved, but they get an access denied message. For me, I just get prompted for the password again, and the "Save Password" Checkbox is suddenly unchecked again